# CO and H2 gas converting to methane question

Tags: gas-laws, gas-phase-chemistry

Why is it when you heat and pressurize CO and H2 it converts to methane? Is it because when you heat the molecules the bonds get weaker and the pressure breaks the bonds and allows them to flow and create new molecule?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there are aspects to consider:

- The increase of *pressure* equates to more particles per unit of volume.  It is like filling a metro with more and more people during rush hour, the propability of  collisions increases.
- The increase of *temperature* equates to a higher kinetic energy of the molecules, so *if* they hit each other, than they do with more momentum.  Gradually, this is like knocking gently at a door (as synonym of *low* temperature), to pound against a door (*warmer*), or even to smash across the door (*hot*, passing the energy barrier).

For the [collision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory), it is the chemical bond which is to break.  The increase of either one of the two parameters increases the chance that bonds break. Their influence is [synergistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy), too.  Of course, there are different bond strengths, requiring different amounts of impact to break.

Try to answer this question -- first for your own:  And what happenz after the collison, where is the energy of the two molecules now (key word [conservation of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy))?  *Why* the product molecules don't fall apart?

> Of course there are product molecules clashing into each other, regenerating
>  the initial molecules ([microscopic reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microscopic_reversibility) of back- and foreward
>  reaction).   This is expressed by the equilibrium constant $K$. 
>  Yet you equally recall that for a given kinetic energy $E_\mathrm{kin}$ a
>  heavy molecule moves slowier, than a lighter one, $$E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$$
>  while some of the impact of collision will be dissipated, e.g., by vibration.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that really clarified it for me!